# PHP counting each new line In textarea field as a new line and wrapping in a list item

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a textarea (advanced custom fields) to capture the users selection.

So the user first answers if there are education areas nearby - yes/no then triggers a radio input with numbers from 1-10, then depending on that, i need to return my information. Right now i am just showing the returned input for the selection of 1 education area.

What want to do, is count the spaces in the text area and wrap each line around an `<li> $var </li>`.
My code below is only returning the second half of my textarea input.

My textarea is:
School
Distance

The below code is only returning

```
<li>Distance</li>
```

My Code

```
if( $edu_close == 'Yes' ) { 
        
        $lines = explode("\n", $edu_close1);
        $count = count ($mylines);

        foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
        $isedu = '<li>'.$lines.'</li>';    
    }

}

elseif( $edu_close == 'No' ) { 

    $noedu = 'Nothing Found';
    
}

    $poidetails .= $isedu;
    $poidetails .= $noedu;
    return $poidetails;
```

[Textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX4f5.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMTy4.png)

Am I doing something wrong that it is only reading the end of the textareas input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overwriting `$isedu` in every cycle. you should have it like this

```
...
$isedu .= '<li>'.$lines.'</li>';
...
```